# onbeforeunload not fired when the iframe containing the page is removed

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, onbeforeunload

I have a webpage `Page1` that defines a working `onbeforeunload` event in which I do some fetch. This `Page1` is loaded in an `iframe1` on another **`domain`**.

**Problem**: When the `iframe1` is `removed` from DOM my `Page1` `beforeunload` event isn't fired at all.

I'm trying locally right now with those files:

`page1.html`:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  console.log('Page1 unloaded')
}
</script>
```

`parent.html`:

```
<div>
    <iframe id='page1' src='./page1.html' ></iframe>
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('page1').remove()" >Remove</button>
```

**Question**: How can I fire the `unload` event of my `Page1` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well the removal of a DOM element is not a navigation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) is not an event related to navigation. for  example, if  I change the  src  of my iframe, i still got my event fired.

Comment: Removing it is not going to fire it, there is no way for the browser to prevent it from being removed.

Comment: I am not trying  to prevent it  from being deleted, just to get my event fired. if  I had control over the parent i could do something with this `parent.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {console.log(e.target.contentWindow.onbeforeunload);});` (ps: tried this and it's working  with a local server)

Comment: I ended up doing  a websocket communication for my needs. Thanks anyway @epascarello

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I ended setting up a `websocket` on my back-end. I was on nodejs env, I used [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Comment: I'm not sure how websocket will solve this problem. Can you provide a code example.

Comment: In the websocket, you implement a disconnect event, that is fired when the user closes the webiew or loses connexion. to identify him you may implement also the connect event and store some data about him.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
e.returnValue = dialogText;
return console.log(dialogText);
};
```

when you click a link or close window you get dialogText in console

Comment: I am not clicking on a link nor  closing the  window, the whole  iframe is removed, but i stay on same page..